# PHP/MongoDB - Pulling records from multiple documents, cursor dies after action on first record

Tags: php, mongodb

I wrote a script to find all records in a collection, and tell me if the user needs to be emailed, does not need to be emailed, or has unsubscribed from email.

I can get it to tell me this information, however when adding an action as simple as echoing a test email template ($m), the scripts dies after passing over one record, resulting in error:

> "Error connecting to MongoDB server the connection has been terminated,
>   and this cursor is dead"

Code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$pastdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
                try {
                    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');
                    $db = $conn->remo;
                    $c = $db->data;
                    $cursor = $c->find( array('last_email'=>array('$nin' => array())));
                    foreach($cursor as $obj) { 
                        if (($obj['last_email'] == null) || ($obj['last_email'] <= $pastdate)) {
                            if($obj['weeklyemail'] === '1') {
                                //Debugging
                                echo 'email'.$obj['email'];
                                //Message to send
                                $m = "Hello ".$obj['first_name'].", this is a test.";
                                echo $m;
                                //Do the mail

                               //Update the date for last_email for user
                                    $newdate = array('$set' => array('last_email' => $date));
                                    $cursor->update(array('email' => ''.$obj['email'].''), $newdate);

                            } else {
                                echo 'unsubscribed'.$obj['email'];
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo 'noemail'.$obj['email'];
                        }
                    }

                // disconnect from server
                $conn->close();
                }  catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
                    die('Error connecting to MongoDB server' . $e->getMessage());
                } catch (MongoException $e) {
                    die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
```

I am confused why the script works, until I simply add an echo. I am expecting the message ($m) to be echoed for each user that needs the email. Once I can get a simple echo to work, I plan on adding the script for the actual mailer part.

Comment: Just curious if this is the whole application listing. Is there possibly something else running in the same userspace? The message would seem to indicate that something else has hung up the connection before the loop is complete. Running off a task scheduler service perhaps?

Comment: There is another, separate script that contacts this mongo db, but as this application is not in production, nobody would be using it when I run this particular script that you see. This is the full script I am running, though. Hopefully that answers your question? The only thing I can think of, is that my code may not be correct to iterate over multiple records. It finds one record, does the action, and stops...

Comment: Oh, and no task scheduler.

Comment: For futher curiousity, try removing the call to `$conn->close()` and see what results you get. The calls should be synchronous, but  at least that would isolate something for a test.

Comment: Same error. So something is killing the script while it runs. It seems to stop right ever echoing the message, for the first record it finds. If I take away the echo, then it will go through all records and execute properly. I don't know why an echo would cause the connection to break?

Comment: I just noticed `$cursor->update` There is no `update` method on a [cursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php). That's not how you process updates in MongoDB. Instead an `update` is a [Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php) method that takes both a query ( used to select the same document currently being iterated ) and an update statement for the data. So you are calling an invalid method. Should be `$c->update()` instead

Comment: It worked. Bravo! Amazing how something so little can break everything. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to post an answer and I will mark it as answered?